# Pass a PHP array to a function?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to'        => 'test@test.com',
    'subject'   => 'testing from curl',
    'html'      => 'testing body',
    'text'      => 'testing body',
    'from'      => 'from@from.com'
);  

/* Put the below into a function */
$request =  'api url goes here';
$session = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
print_r($response);
/* Put the above into a function */
```

Basically I want to put the above code between the comments into a function, so that I can set the params and then do the following:

```
sendthat($params);
```

This is to simply clean up my page, and have the curl request grabbing the array via a function.

How can I pass the array to a function?

Comment: Like you pass any other argument/value.

Comment: UH? Well, the same way you pass a variable...

Comment: your code _already_ passes an array to a function (second `curl_setopt` call).

Answer (score 5):

```
function whatever ($params) {

    $request =  'api url goes here';
    $session = curl_init($request);
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);
    print_r($response);
}

$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to'        => 'test@test.com',
    'subject'   => 'testing from curl',
    'html'      => 'testing body',
    'text'      => 'testing body',
    'from'      => 'from@from.com'
);



whatever($params);
```

An array assigned to a variable is no different than any other type of value assigned to a variable.

Comment: Thanks, the only non sarcastic reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
function_name($params);
```

and in function

```
extract($params);
```

(do it only when you're sure you know what you're doing)